# Creating Pearson Correlation metrics using Tensorflow Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, metrics, tensor, pearson-correlation

I wanted to create a pearson correlation coefficient metrics using tensorflow tensor. They do have a tensorflow probability package https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/correlation but this have dependency issues with the current version of tensorflow. I am afraid that this will cause the cuda to break. Any standalone implementation of pearson correlation coefficient metrics in tensorflow will help...

So I want something like this:

```py
def p_corr(y_true, y_pred):
    # calculate the pearson correlation coefficient here
    return pearson_correlation_coefficient
```

Here y_true and y_pred will be a list of numbers of same dimension.

Comment: What dependency issues did you run into? If you check the TFP releases page, it will indicate which TF version each release is compatible with. If you're using a fixed TF version, you should be able to find the corresponding TFP version there. https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/releases.

Comment: There are some weird CUDA errors in that GPU server which I am using. They probably said to use the latest TF version, at least greater than 2.6. Like every time I upgrade a version, the nvidia-smi breaks and I had to reinstall everything. Not sure about why this thing happens, so I thought of finding a standalone solution. The answer that I posted works fine, I guess. I am just too afraid to install the newest version and mess up the dependencies again. Hence, I settled with that function for now.

Comment: Which TF version are you able to successfully use (ie, with your handcoded solution below)?

Comment: TF version 2.4.1

Comment: Can you try tensorflow-probability==0.12.2 ? It is compatible with tf 2.4 and has tfp.stats.correlation

Comment: conda install tensorflow-probability==0.12.2 ?

Comment: I've not used conda very much but yes something like that. You can print tfp.__version__ to check what is installed.

Comment: TFP version '0.14.0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245895/discussion-between-chris-suter-and-jimut123).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```py
from keras import backend as K

def pearson_r(y_true, y_pred):
    # use smoothing for not resulting in NaN values
    # pearson correlation coefficient
    # https://github.com/WenYanger/Keras_Metrics
    epsilon = 10e-5
    x = y_true
    y = y_pred
    mx = K.mean(x)
    my = K.mean(y)
    xm, ym = x - mx, y - my
    r_num = K.sum(xm * ym)
    x_square_sum = K.sum(xm * xm)
    y_square_sum = K.sum(ym * ym)
    r_den = K.sqrt(x_square_sum * y_square_sum)
    r = r_num / (r_den + epsilon)
    return K.mean(r)
```